# phone number RegEx not working for some strings

Tags: regex, vba

I want to recognize phone number as 9 consecutive figures which can be separated by white spaces, non-breaking spaces etc. with regEx "(\s*\d\s*){9}"

I run VBA macro (JS RegEx) and here are example strings which work fine with above RegEx:

ul. 27 Grudnia 16, tel. 21 287 31 61, fax 61 286 69 60 –

ul. Wrzosowa 110/120/222, kom. 692 601 428

And here is an example where phone number is not detected in VBA, but is detected by RegEx JS online tools:

al. Mazowieckiego 63, kom. 622 769 694 –

Strings which are detected and these which are not, have the same structure, so I have no idea why VBA doesn't detect phone number in some of them.

Comment: Your regex worked for me, what isn't working? Working example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lA7bA0/1)

Comment: I couldn't find (quickly enough) much info regarding `VBA` regex, and because it's microslop you wont have all the features that a robust and mature regex engine will have. Follow the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=VS.85).aspx) to save you banging your head and turning into a microslop developer ;)

Comment: [`(\s*\d){9}`](https://regex101.com/r/jQ9jT5/2) works very well with `al. Mazowieckiego 63, kom. 622 769 694 –` (działa bardzo dobrze).

Comment: I already posted an answer, the problem was not that non working string has some different pattern, but that exceptions happen for seemingly same item and what could cause it.

Comment: It is still off topic. Please edit the question by adding details from your answer that does not actually solve the issue with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

It came out that VBA changed some strings to look in - replaced a whitespace - chr(32) with a non breaking chr(160).

Removing chr(160) from string to look in solves the problem.
Also I will try to find RegEx which will let non-breaking spaces, because \s* doesn't do so, at least in VBA.